# How would one implement the pick function using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

The [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick) hints on a `pick` function, which is only declared and not implemented. I tried to implement a simplified version the following way:

```js
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): Pick<T, K> {
  return { [key]: obj[key] }
}
```

I get the following error: "TS2322: Type `{ [x: string]: T[K]; }` is not assignable to type `Pick`." I am wondering why `key` is generalized to `string` even if it is declared to be `keyof T`. Primarily, how could one implement `pick` without using `any` or casting like `as Pick<T, K>`? I also want to clarify that I do not want to use `Partial<T>` as a return type. I want to return a "slice" of the original type that contains exactly one field chosen by the caller.

Note: I also tried the equivalent:

```js
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): { [key in K]: T[K] } {
  return { [key]: obj[key] }
}
```

This (of course) gives essentially the same error. I am on TypeScript version `4.7.4`.

Comment: Please clarify which of your questions is your primary question.  Do you want to know why `key` is generalized to `string`?  Or do you want to know how to implement `pick` without using type assertions?

Comment: Especially the second part. I would like to write this function without type assertions. Using `any` hides possible errors. Using `as ...` hides possible errors. I wonder if it is possible to implement `pick` without type assertions and if not why. To me it looks like all the information to the compiler should be available.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need at least one type assertion somewhere, or something else unsound, due to a longstanding bug/limitation; see [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).  There's a bit of unsoundness in your code, since `pick({a: 0, b: 1}, Math.random()<0.5?"a":"b")` should presumably produce a value of type `{a: number} | {b: number}`, but your version claims to produce `{a: number, b: number}`.  My suggestion here would be [this](https://tsplay.dev/wepKYW).  If that answers your question I can write up an answer; if not,what am I missing?

Comment: I am afraid that you answered my question, yes. Sad but true. Hope it will be fixed. Thanks for the bug link and the improvement. Your point also works with `pick<Foo, "a" | "b">({a: 0, b: 1}, "a")`, which might be a little bit simpler to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a limitation in TypeScript where a computed property key whose type is not a single string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) is widened all the way to `string`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) for more information.  So, for now, in order to use a computed property with a type narrower than `string` you will need to do something a little unsafe like use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

---

One reason there hasn't already been a fix for this issue is that you can't simply say that `{[k]: v}` is of type `Record<typeof k, typeof v>`.  If `typeof k` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (or if it is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type, which might end up being specified as a union type), then `Record<typeof k, typeof v>` has *all* the keys from the union type, whereas the true type of `{[k]: v}` should have just *one* of those keys.

You would run into the same problem with your `pick()` implementation.  The type of `pick(obj, key)` **is not necessarily `Pick<T, K>`**, precisely because `K` might be specified with a union type.    This complication makes things a bit harder to deal with.

The "right" type for `pick(obj, key)` is to *distribute* `Pick<T, K>` across unions in `K`.  You could either use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) like `K extends keyof T ? Pick<T, K> : never` or a distributive object type like `{[P in K]-?: Pick<T, K>}[K]`.

---

For example, if you have the following,

```
interface Foo {
    a: number,
    b: number
}
const foo: Foo = { a: 0, b: 1 }
const someKey = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b";
// const someKey: "a" | "b"

const result = pick(foo, someKey);
```

You *don't* want `result` to be of type `Pick<Foo, "a" | "b">`, which is just `Foo`.  Instead, we need to define `pick()` to return one of the distributive types above, and we need to use a type assertion to do it:

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
    return { [key]: obj[key] } as K extends keyof T ? Pick<T, K> : never
}
```

And that results in the following result:

```
const result = pick(foo, someKey);
// const result: Pick<Foo, "a"> | Pick<Foo, "b">
```

So `result` is *either* a `Pick<Foo, "a">` or a `Pick<Foo, "b">`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABxhA1gHgCoBpEDSiApgB5TFgAmAzousQJ5zCLYB8AFHAEYBWALjb4GjIQQCUiAN4AoRAsQAnYlBBKk0xAG1RAXSG8+upnsQBfRAEM6RMhWp1RLNogD8iAAposeQu0QhMGIAN2IlWXNZWRgwCiVgKwhiRAAxODgZeUUrIJAAWx5w3GyFHjzC8MjZCAQaKERgDKF0zIBeGWshAAZ8csQARgsauoaaOHziAiZEDoBZKygACwA6JStqCc4pTERulYBWd0QAIisTwNOeE4BuWQB6e8RasHrEccnpsVPzxAAfK4nEavBoqGggAA2DQ6qAwnCacHwHymTAkd0ez1GymI4KhQm8GEwrXwZxOAQBBKwxMB7GiQA)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build the object and then return it. Something similar to this

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): Pick<T, K> {
  let ret: any = {}  
  ret[key] = obj[key]

  return ret
}
```

You can see this working [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABxhA1gHgCoBpEDSiApgB5TFgAmAzousQJ5zCLYB8AFHAEYBWALjb4GjIQQCUQgAposeQu0QBvAFCJEAG2JREAJx1CAhmEaIAvCoC+G9fp0BtUQF0LiXnydNnquwaggekj+qla+EAg0uh5uaohGQgCMAAy46jxCAEwAzGmIEEIARBCFoeGRcNoAdJpwAOacqBjc-PiFRoUSEr5N6C18bWAIZDBRMGB1op2qQA)

Comment: I can replace line 3 with `ret["nonexistingkey"] = obj[key]` and the compiler would not raise an error. The complexity of the function is minimal and the error is unlikely to happen. I wonder if it is possible to implement `pick` without assuming that my types are correct. It feels like an easy problem.